# Google Analytics not tracking views in IOS Ionic 3 Application with GTAG.js

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics, ionic3, gtag.js

I'm setting up Google Analytics in my application, I already track all events and pages.

When I look the Google Analytics, the android is working perfectly, otherwise the iOS is not tracking any view or event.

I tried change the iOS version, but nothing change.

```
<script src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXX-1"></script>

<script>

  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}

  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXX-1', {
    'page_title' : "Ionic App",
    'page_path': 'OpenApp'
  });

</script>
```

```js
declare let gtag: Function;

@Injectable()
export class GoogleAnalyticsProvider {

  trackPagesHandler(view) {

    let pagePath = view.instance.constructor.name;

    gtag('config', 'UA-XXX-1', {
      'page_title': "Ionic App",
      'page_path': pagePath
    });

  }

  trackEventHandler(eventCategory, eventAction, eventLabel) {

    const eventData = {
      event_category: eventCategory,
      event_label: eventLabel,
    };

    gtag('event', eventAction, eventData);

  }

}

</script>
```

```js
this.app.viewDidEnter.subscribe((view: ViewController) => this.ga.trackPagesHandler(view));
```

I want to know a way to make works in both platform.

Comment: Have you find a way to make it work ?
I have the opposite behavior : work on iOS, not on android (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62306415/google-analytics-not-tracking-views-in-android-ionic-3-application-with-gtag-js)